# Create a running sum graph in dc.js

Tags: sum, dc.js, crossfilter, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a running sum in crossfilter to use with dc.js.
I have a set of records like the following :

```
records = [{"date":"2014-01-01","field1":"value1","field2":"value11","value_field":-20},
           {"date":"2014-01-02","field1":"value2","field2":"value12","value_field":100},
           {"date":"2014-01-03","field1":"value1","field2":"value11","value_field":-10},
           {"date":"2014-01-04","field1":"value2","field2":"value12","value_field":150},
           ]
```

So far I have created a barGraph which plays nicely with the other dimensions but I would like to be able to show an line graph of the theoretical field `runnning_total` (along the dimension date).

To have it done in crossfilter would allow me to then group using the `fieldx` fields and easily get the same running total graph but restricted to a subgroup of values using dc.js.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I know the op already built a solution but after struggling with for a while I was able to crack it, so posting it here if someone else searches for it.

using the cumulative for the following: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/W9AvkP_dZ0U

Running Sum:

```
var _group   = dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return 1;});

var group = {
all:function () {
 var cumulate = 0;
 var g = [];
 _group.all().forEach(function(d,i) {
   cumulate += d.value;
   g.push({key:d.key,value:cumulate})
 });
 return g;
}
```

};

for Trailing Twelve Month calculation:

```
var _group   = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.revenue;});
var group = {
all:function () {
var g = [];
_group.all().forEach(function(d,i) {
    var cumulate = 0;
    var monthcount =0;
    var dt =new Date( d.key);
    var ct =  new Date(d.key);
    ct.setFullYear(ct.getUTCFullYear() -1);
    _group.all().forEach(function(d2,i) {
        var dt2 = new Date(d2.key);
        if(dt2 <= dt && dt2 > ct){
            cumulate += d2.value;
            monthcount++; 
        }
    })
    if(monthcount>=11){
        console.log( ' Dt ' + dt + ' ' + cumulate + ' months ' + monthcount); 
        g.push({key:d.key,value:cumulate})
        }
    });
                return g;
            }
        };
```

Comment: revisiting this 6 years later (damn!), this is the right solution. Pay attention to the sorting of your group if it's along a time axis and it will need to be adapted to each specific situation but this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are grouping across date (as per your `date dimension`), the `reduce()` function would be used to perform aggregations **grouped by date**, as per the highlighted cells in my Mickey Mouse example below:

[image: Aggregating across fruits]

With a running total you'd need to perform an entirely different operation, looping down the rows:

[image]

You can aggregate the data and then append the running total field as follows. I've also included an example of how to calculate an average value, using the `reduce` function:

```
records = [{ "date": "2014-01-01", "field1": "value1", "field2": "value11", "value_field": -20 },
    { "date": "2014-01-02", "field1": "value2", "field2": "value12", "value_field": 100 },
    { "date": "2014-01-03", "field1": "value1", "field2": "value11", "value_field": -10 },
    { "date": "2014-01-04", "field1": "value2", "field2": "value12", "value_field": 150 }
];


var cf = crossfilter(records);                                 

var dimensionDate = cf.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.date;
    });


function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    p.total += v.value_field;
    p.count++;
    p.average = p.total / p.count;
    return p;
}
function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    p.total -= v.value_field;
    p.count--;
    p.average = p.count ? p.total / p.count : 0;
    return p;
}
function reduceInitial() {
    return {
        total: 0,
        count: 0,
        average: 0,
    };
}



var average = dimensionDate.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial).all();

var averageWithRunningTotal = appendRuningTotal(average);  

function appendRuningTotal(average) {
    var len = average.length,
        runningTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        runningTotal += average[i].value.total;
        average[i].RunningTotal = runningTotal;
    }

    return average;
}
```

And this returns the following:

```
{"key":"2014-01-01","value":{"total":-20,"count":1,"average":-20},"RunningTotal":-20}
{"key":"2014-01-02","value":{"total":100,"count":1,"average":100},"RunningTotal":80}
{"key":"2014-01-03","value":{"total":-10,"count":1,"average":-10},"RunningTotal":70}
{"key":"2014-01-04","value":{"total":150,"count":1,"average":150},"RunningTotal":220}
```

Comment: So I managed to show the initial running total line using `.valueAccessor`. But what I am still missing is the ability for the running total to update automatically when I select one of the groups in an other barcharts for example. I would want to show only the running total for the selected value of one of the fields. To get back to my example : what would be the running total for only the `field1=value1` records ?

Comment: You can just change the p.total value, in the reduce functions, to look at field1. So from this: `p.total += v.value_field;` To this: `p.total += v.value1;` If you want totals of all your fields, then just  make up new variables for them in the `reduceInital` function and assign to them in the `reduceAdd` and `reduceRemove` functions. :)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your comment but I don't think it applies in my case. In my case, instead of `Apples` and `Bananas`, I have `Name` and `City`. Let's assume my `value` field is the daily number of oranges sold to that specific person in that city. What I want to show is 1. a lineChart of the runningTotal of number of oranges sold along the dateDimension 2. a bar chart of the total number of oranges sold by city over the period.

How do I get the lineChart to update with the correct runningTotal when I cick on the bar for one single city ?

Comment: I don't actually use dc.js so am just here with crossfilter knowledge. Is it that you need to know how to group by date and city, at once? i.e. clicking the line should filter the data to London and by date.

Comment: OK. Clicking the bar should only show the running total of oranges sold for all people in London by date.

Comment: I used the `reduceSum` pre-built function on my one and only value field. I have 3 or 4 "criteria" fields that I would like to show the running total by date for.

Comment: To group by multiple selection fields, you can specify the dimension function to include all these fields. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766986/is-it-possible-to-group-by-multiple-dimensions-in-crossfilter) on how to do this. In essence what you need to do:`var dimensionDate = cf.dimension(function (d) {
        return 'date=' + d.date+';city='+d.City;
    });` Note that to get the date back out of this object you will then need to split the key between the 'date=' and ';' strings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47314/discussion-between-chapo-and-ninjapixel)

Comment: I ended up creating a cumulativeSum value field taking all criterias into account in my source data beforehand instead of struggling with creating it live on the webpage. Everything works as intended now with a `reduceSum` grouping on that field.

Comment: @ninjaPixel Is is possible to get running (sum(field1)/sum(field2)) in crossfilter. If so, how???I have started using crossfilter very recently and following the example at http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/stock.js , I tried implementing the same but I am having issues. Can you help me with it?Please